# How to check if a user has a role in a server through dms (discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I don't understand on how would I do this.

My current code is:

```
let server = Bot.guilds.cache.get('816022730926456852')
var memberRole = server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "access")
let member = server.members.cache.get(msg.author.id)

if (!member.roles.has(memberRole)) {
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean checking a users role in a specific server. You would do it like this:

```
let server = bot.guilds.cache.get("guild id");
let memberRole = message.member.roles.cache.some(
  (role) => role.name === "RoleName"
);
let member = server.members.cache.get(message.author.id);

if (!member.roles.has(memberRole)) {
  return;
}
```

Should work :)

Comment: It doesn't work, it says this: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Comment: let memberRole = msg.member.roles.cache.some(

Comment: Yeah I don't know why but if you can fix it lmk